# Error in proof by strong induction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

$ \textbf{Question:} $ If an experiment can be performed in $ k $ steps such that the first step can be done in $ n_{1} $ ways, the second step can be done in $ n_{2} $ ways, ..., and the last step can be done in $ n_{k} $ ways, then the total number of ways to perform this experiment is $ n_{1} + n_{2} + \dots + n_{k}. $

Here is the proof using strong induction for this $ \textbf{false} $ statement, can someone help me find the error in the proof?

$ \textbf{Proof:} $ Let $ P(k) $ be the statement that "if an experiment can be performed in $ k $ steps such that the first step can be done in $ n_{1} $ ways, the second step can be done in $ n_{2} $ ways, ..., and the last step can be done in $ n_{k} $ ways, then the total number of ways to perform this experiment is $ n_{1} + n_{2} + \dots + n_{k}. $"

Base case: If the experiment only has $ 1 $ step, then there is $ n_{1} $ ways to do it, so $ P(1) $ is true. Now suppose that $ P(1),P(2), \dots, P(k) $ is true for $ k > 1. $ Consider $ P(k + 1), $ since if the experiment has $ k + 1 $ steps, it can be done by first doing the first $ k $ steps following by the $ k + 1 $ steps, thus the total number of possible ways to do the experiment is $ (n_{1} + n_{2} + \dots + n_{k}) + n_{k + 1} $ (since $ P(2) $ is true). Hence $ P(k + 1) $ is true as well.

Comment: The basis case proves for $P(1)$, which is fine. But the induction step proves $P(k + 1)$ given $P(k)$ when $k > 1$. This doesn't prove $P(2)$.

Comment: By saying "suppose it is true for k > 1" and " since  P (2) is true" you pretty much tipped you hand.  We *can't* assume that as the base case was only k=1.  And we have no freaking idea that P (2) is true.  Had you not said that it'd be a lot harder to find the error.  In fact, why *did* you say those ridiculous things.  Why didn't you say $k \ge 1$ and "since P (1) is true"?

Answer (score 1):

The induction step is erroneous because the inference used is unjustified (and, in fact, fallacious).

From the universal principle of counting: the number of ways to perform two subtasks *in serial* is the product of the ways to perform each of the subtasks.

Thus if the first $k$ steps can be preformed in $\sum_{j=1}^k n_j$ ways, and the next step can be performed in $n_{k+1}$ ways, then the first $k+1$ steps of the experiment can be performed in $\bbox[lightpink,0.25ex]{~n_{k+1}\sum_{j=1}^k n_j~}$ ways.

This is clearly not generally $~\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}n_j~$ as you would require for the prof to be sound.

**tl;dr** $P(2)$ is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The induction step fails.  Think about $P(2)$.  You have $n_1$ ways to do the first step.  For each of those, you have $n_2$ ways to do the second step.  The proof misses the point that you then have $n_1n_2$ instead of $n_1+n_2$ ways to do the first two steps.